# Need To Close Handlers of Logger

Tags: java, logging, finalizer

Is it needed to close all `handlers` of a `java.util.logging.Logger` manually? e.g. in the finalizer of the class?

Comment: `java.util.logging.Logger` and `java.util.logging.Handler`

Answer (score 0):

If you are removing the handler from the logger then you'll have to close it.  Otherwise, if the handler is still attached to the logger a shutdown hook installed by the LogManager will close the handler for you.